# Using ModelBuilder Model from ArcMap 9.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, arcgis-9.3

I have a model that was created in ModelBuilder.  I think the original version is 9.3 ArcMap.  I'm trying to run it and it won't run because it was created in an older version.  So I would have to rebuild the model in my current version of ArcMap which is 10.7.1.

Is there a way to upgrade the model without having to rebuild it?

Comment: Reverse compatibility is usually only supported three revs back, so you've been outside that window since 10.3 (which is also now retired). It seems you might need to rebuild the model.

Comment: There were *big* changes in the geoprocessor between 9.x and 10.x, if you can open and interrogate the model that should give you a reasonable idea of what tools you'd be wanting in ArcGIS 10.x, however in some instances the difference is so vast that the old model is of no help. You could try exporting to a python script and then see if that runs - it's worth a shot, if it doesn't work it's only a short time invested - much less than trying to recreate from scratch.